# How do I build a Debian and RPM binary for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: rpm, visual-studio-code, deb

I know that Visual Studio Code (VSCode) has official EULA-licensed Debian and RPM binary releases, but I would like to build my own custom freely-licensed Debian/RPM binaries (like with a custom desktop launcher file) from VSCode's source code. With the Atom text editor I would run `script/grunt mkdeb` for the Debian binary and `script/grunt mkrpm` for the RPM binary. As for VSCode I cannot see any instructions on how to do this. I have looked at the source code build instructions (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source), hoping to find instructions on how to do this, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current way to do this is calling into the gulp tasks in [gulpfile.vscode.linux.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/build/gulpfile.vscode.linux.js):

- `vscode-linux-ia32-build-deb`
- `vscode-linux-ia32-build-rpm`
- `vscode-linux-x64-build-deb`
- `vscode-linux-x64-build-rpm`

These are of course subject to change. Also remember that unofficial builds may also lose some functionality such as extensions and auto-updating ([which is on it's way](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/229)).